# Replace a series of repeated occurrences in a list?

Tags: python, duplicates

I would like to replace the consecutive occurrences with the first appearance.

For example if I currently have a list

```
[1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5, 1, 1, 1]
```

the desired output will be

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1]
```

I know that I can definitely do this by using a for loop to iterate through the list but is there a more pythonic way of doing it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without import anything:

```
l = [1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5, 1, 1, 1]
[v for i, v in enumerate(l) if i == 0 or v != l[i-1]]

# [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1]
```

Answer (score 4):

Use [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby)
:

```
from itertools import groupby
x=[1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5, 1, 1, 1]
print([i[0] for i in groupby(x)])
```